# Hyphenate character inside a table

Tags: longtable, hyphenation, split, active-characters

I am generating a long table that has 3 columns. The content of the table contains words that contain underscore such as "ABCD_243_SSD_FCA_SDD" and using the hyphenate package I managed to break the content to the next line when the word does not fit the column width.

The problem is that I get an arrow as the hyphenation character:

[image]

How can I replace this arrow with "-" or with whitespace ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a small [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get  and to test possible suggestions.

Comment: Please tell us how the columns are defined. If the column that contains `ABCD_243_SSD_FCA_SDD` has a fixed width -- e.g., `p{2cm}` -- you could load the `seqsplit` package and write `\seqsplit{ABCD_243_SSD_FCA_SDD}` to force an automaticline break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want `_` to act like an explict hyphenation point you can tell TeX that is what it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\catcode`\_12 \hyphenchar\font`\_}p{2cm}}
  aaa & ABCD_243_SSD_FCA_SDD\\
  bbb & ZZZ_1234_THIS_THAT_THING\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```